# Does philosophy involve long inferential chains?

Tags: logic, epistemology, metaphilosophy

An inferential chain is a series of inferences where each depends on the previous in sequence. "From A we conclude B, from B we conclude C, and from C we conclude D." That would be a chain of length three, as it has three inferences.

In contrast, "A supports D, B supports D, and C also supports D" is not a length 3 inferential chain, because the order of the three inferences can be rearranged without altering the argument. The longest inferential chain in that argument is only length 1.

To be more specific, we can consider an argument as a directed acyclic graph from premises to intermediate conclusions towards final conclusions, with an arrow from each justifying statement pointing towards the statement it justifies. An inferential chain is a directed path in this graph.

In mathematics we do have long inferential chains. Mathematical proofs may run into the hundreds of pages, and the longest inferential chain through such a proof would also be very long. This is possible because each step of mathematical reasoning is very certain. So we can put many links in the chain with a low risk of it breaking. (Still, very long and complicated mathematical proofs are not infrequently found to have flaws.)

In ordinary common-sense reasoning, inferential chains tend to be much shorter. "It's raining today, so I'll bring an umbrella," has only length 1. One good explanation for why common-sense inferential chains are short, is that common-sense inferences are uncertain. If each inference is only 90% sure, then if you chain 10 of them together, the chain is only 0.9^10 = 35% likely to be intact without broken links. So in ordinary common-sense reasoning we prefer to build broad, rather than deep, arguments. We prefer to consider the pros and cons that add or subtract directly from a claim, rather than extrapolating too deeply in too many steps from the available evidence.

In fact, often, common-sense arguments are neither deep *nor* broad; people find it difficult to subjectively weigh too many pros and cons, especially once there are more pros and cons than will fit in short-term memory. And so we often fall back on picking out one or a few pieces of evidence as most important, allowing ourselves to ignore or override lesser evidence.

How can we characterize the inferential chains used in philosophy? Are they long, like mathematics, or short, like common-sense reasoning?

It's my feeling that legitimate inferential chains in philosophy are short. Because in philosophy (except for logic) we don't have the luxury of reasoning with perfect certainty, and rather must appeal to intuition and analogy most of the time, long inferential chains have a high chance of being flawed. The situation is more like common-sense reasoning than mathematics.

Philosophical papers are often very long. But famous specific arguments in philosophy can usually be summarized within just a few paragraphs. Without the luxury of logical certainty, an excessively long argument becomes unwieldy and unsure, and we are unable to fit the whole thing in our heads or reason effectively about it. The length of philosophical papers often comes from comparisons to other works and examples or hypotheticals, rather than from having a long central argument. Is this perception of the state of affairs correct?

Comment: For sure, very long arguments... IMO very seldom they can be "formalized" as strict inferential chains.

Comment: The shortness of common sense is deceptive. Much of the length is folded into premises taken for granted, and the omitted arguments for them replaced with intuitions and unanalyzed surmises from shared background. Another difference with mathematics is that the reasoning is heuristic/abductive, not formal, hence not as sensitive to long chain errors. Philosophy gets to unfold all of that and weave in scientific and other sources on top of it. The "famous specific arguments" are just toy models for novices with the substance likewise folded into premises, which are what really is argued for.

Comment: @Conifold I would rather say that the premises in common sense are not arrived at by logical means at all. We've tried to mimic common sense via logical deduction, e.g. Cyc, and it does not work well. GPT-3 works much better for common sense than Cyc, and relies on pattern recognition rather than long chains of logic. Why do you say heuristic/abductive reasoning would be less sensitive to long chain errors? There don't seem to be long inferential chains in science - except where the foundational elements are subject to exact mathematics, e.g. chemistry, physics.

Comment: @Conifold Give an example of a long inferential chain in philosophy (more than a few paragraphs.) Let's diagram it. I think we will find it's broad, or that its length derives from discursions, clarifications, and examples not part of the argument, rather than being a long inferential chain.

Comment: I don't see how "common-sense" inference chains are even inference chains. If they are analogistic or probabilistic- then how are they a "series of inferences where one follows the other" .... it's apples to oranges. Calling them inference chains is a mistake. IMO there are practically no inference chains in common parlance or non formal logic based philosophy. However, beyond that caveat which is easily fixed by calling them informal inference chains, I agree with your assessment. The length comes from trying to justify the jumps in the informal inference chain, if the inference chain

Comment: is too long, the paper's length would explode to an unweidly size. Also, each informal justification allows for a counter-justification, and so holes will form in the argument. So funny enough, the longer the informal inference chain, the longer the counter informal inference chain will be. Which I guess sums up the principle of the strength of simplicity and brevity in Rhetorical Argument

Comment: I guess we have a different idea of what an argument is, discursions, clarifications, and examples are an essential part of informal arguments, as I understand it. Deductive chains of formal mathematics are just a degenerate special case and a poor model for logic in the full sense, which is why Cyc-style theorem provers are lousy. This is Toulmin's view in The Uses of Argument, for example. Informal arguments are less error-prone exactly because they do not rely on checking elementary steps, the same way mathematicians work in practice.

Comment: Aside from richer logical apparatus of informal arguments, the difference is largely stylistic. Long proofs of mathematics can be, and often are in mature expositions, presented as short, with key claims folded into lemmas. The short "famous arguments" are just such top level sketches. Instead of talking about lemmas, philosophers say "and now I'll argue for the premises" in their sketches. Kant, for example, spends a lot of space even to establish terminology with argumentative support that his terms relate to each other the way he says before getting into "proofs".

Comment: @Conifold I would never suggest that arguments must be deductive. Examples can be part of the argument, but typically they add breadth rather than depth. You say something like, "A implies B, which implies C, which implies D. For example, X is a plausible or actual scenario where A, B, C, and D occur." X is (usually weak) extra support for D but it goes in parallel to the main argument A->B->C->D, rather than in sequence, so does not increase the length of the inferential chain. Discursions by definition are not part of the argument.

Comment: It's somewhat ambiguous where clarifications (of the definition of a term) stand in relation to the argument. If you draw an argument map, definitions have a special status; they aren't exactly statements, they're the context used to interpret statements. If the argument can be stated without the clarification and most would understand what was meant, then the clarification shouldn't be counted as a separate step. On the other hand, some arguments are all about how a term ought to be defined, and a clarification would be counted there.

Comment: Standard definitions of [proof length](https://users.math.cas.cz/~pudlak/length.pdf) count parts that run "in parallel" additively. I suspect that one can "shorten" proofs dramatically by parallel rearrangement otherwise (by analogy to computations). This makes me question breadth/depth distinction generally, they are not preserved by deductive equivalence. Philosophical arguments can rarely be set up without explication of terms and their interrelations (formal analog is "definition" by axiomatization), discursions/digressions often provide meta-theoretical support of argument structure, etc.

Comment: @Conifold Well, I didn't ask about the length of a proof, I asked about the length of the longest inferential chain (which I defined). Yes, the "same" argument can be diagrammed in different ways with a different longest inferential chain length. However, there is a real and relevant difference between an argument that lists 20 pieces of evidence each independently supporting one conclusion, and an argument that builds out an extrapolation 20 steps long where each step depends on the previous.

Comment: In general, you (physically and metaphysically) have a unique and deepest goal determined by a rule (example, your objective can be different, this is just an example: _I must survive_). All other rules are built upon such rule. However, 1) it's difficult to discriminate the boundaries between the rules of _what is_ and _what is not_ philosophy, 2) all rules are related somehow with all others, so, it's very difficult to identify the path between two rules, and to decide "this is/is not a long inferential chain", and 3) "long" is subjective: four (or four hundred) rules is long?

Comment: I share the intuition to some extent but your metric looks fishy to me. Logical means are just too elastic. "Pieces of evidence" can be conjoined into Evidence and a star graph with edges leading to a single vertex converted into a chain of the same length leading from Evidence "piecemeal". It can be lengthened further by fine-graining. One needs to standardize deductive parsing somehow and impose non-syntactic restrictions to block such merging and splitting. Even then, it may work to compare arguments with shared vocabulary and deductive system, but otherwise it compares apples to oranges.

Comment: I am also concerned that informal arguments are not properly represented by directed graphs of the deductive model. If they include warrants and backing (to use Toulmin's terms) then there are second order changes to the "deductive system" in the course of the argument. The right metric would have to measure that in addition to reparsing definitional manipulations. Hintikka worked on some aspects of it, and maybe such metric can be found and will show a divide between philosophy and math. But the more I think about it the more superficial intuitions about the result seem to be.

Comment: @Conifold Warrants and backing are just more propositions that fit into the argument map in the same way as other propositions. There's no need to grant them special status or treat them differently. Also, the graphs I'm talking about are not "of the deductive model"; "inference" is a general term that does not only mean deduction. Definitions do need special treatment, but they are in principle just syntactic sugar because you could, in principle, write every proposition only in some agreed-on base language. ZFC lacks a way to introduce custom terms, for example, and does not need one.

Comment: Nah. Inference is a general term, but the structure of arguments even in Toulmin's model will not produce the graphs you want. And if you force it your resulting graphs will lose relevance. The same with other "in principle" conversions, they are only input/output equivalent to the originals, "depth" characteristics are hopelessly distorted. Look at Hintikka's work on depth/surface information. Even if commensurable translations could be made "in principle" the process is convoluted and opaque to intuition, so we cannot tell much until it is actually done.

Comment: @Conifold Wherever possible we should simplify, not complicate. If you look at an argument map as a causal diagram, it is clear that nodes representing statements and arrows representing inferences are all you need. Each inference can be translated as, "mental patterns A, B, C, brought to attention together, *cause* a reasonable person to adopt mental pattern D." It is clear that all thought is a matter of successive adoption of mental patterns based on prior ones. And thus all thought can be modeled as a causal graph, which is also an acyclic graph of inferences.

Comment: From the perspective of a causal graph of mental patterns we don't even need a special case for definitions. (And it is good to eliminate special cases, where possible; we should obey the urge to simplify and generalize.) "Having the tendency to apply definition D for term T" is actually just a node in the graph - a mental pattern a person uses, in conjunction with other mental patterns representing statements, to produce new mental patterns representing new statements. (Note that the definition is used in parallel with the statements it contextualizes, not in sequence with them.)

Comment: No, the start at observation. A' (my observation) *is* A (the thing itself). And then you start the inferences or seek further observations.

Answer (score 2):

My recollection of books, papers and talks on philosophy is that very few of them reason step by step through a long chain of reasoning to reach a remote conclusion. It would be interesting, IMHO, to see an analysis of philosophical texts broken down by the amount of space they dedicate to different facets of a case, eg background, rubbishing, sorry, assessing the works of other philosophers, defining terms, presenting examples, reaching interim conclusions to form the foundation for the next step, and so on. The point about common-sense reasoning is that it can be concise because it takes so much for granted. If you start to unpick the implicit premises underlying much common-sense reasoning, you quickly get into a mire of ambiguity and unsubstantiated assumptions. In any event, much of philosophy- like much of other academic work that is inherently not mathematical- is not about chains of reasoning, per se, but about promoting a particular perspective on a topic, or a particular schema for breaking a complicated subject down into more digestible chunks. Take, for example, literary analysis, and the different flavours of it that have risen and fallen in influence over the last hundred and fifty years. How they differ is mainly in perspective and focus- where one focuses on the purported meaning of the author, another focuses on meaning as a creation of the reader. You cannot say that one is more 'correct' than the other, that one has done a better job of taking logical steps- all you can really do is decide whether one has taken you along a more informative route to a more advantageous vantage point for overlooking the subject matter.

Answer (score 2):

Three major examples of philosophical treatises—Plato's *Republic*, Immanuel Kant's *Critique of Pure Reason*, and John Rawls' *A Theory of Justice*—all involve fairly long chains of reasoning, principally deductive but admixed with an implicit appeal to what Rawls identified as reflective equilibrium (a more coherentistic function, in counterpoint to the implicit foundationalism of well-founded deductive trees). Of those three examples, Plato's is the most free-form, being a dialogue after all, but both on its own terms and in relation to the extended Platonic *corpus*, it expresses Plato's interest in inferential understanding and apprehension by the by.

Now, Rawls in *his* book says that (moral) philosophy should aim for all the precision/rigor of geometry; he weaves simple, if perspicuous, geometrical illustrations into his theory (the curves in §§12-13), works out the premises from which the two principles of justice can be derived, and then reinforces those premises and principles in Part 3 by further combined appeals to both strait deduction and more Quinean web-of-belief considerations. Altogether, he does say (§87) that he has not actually used a purely, rigidly deductive method, neither only a more "naturalistic" one, but per his overarching inclusivism he has brought in whatever reasoning both intuition and intellection support as resonant with the goal of moral philosophy (which he says is, among other things, to find possibilities of agreement where none are believed to exist).

Next, consider other seminal (or at least naively "canonical") works such as Descartes' *Meditations on First Philosophy*. If one arranged such a text as numbered sentences, one would have a document with as many steps as many a solid mathematical proof (c.f. [*Rules for the Direction of the Mind*](https://learning.hccs.edu/faculty/robert.tierney/phil1301-3/substantive-course-materials/unit-iii/descartes-rules-for-the-direction-of-the-mind/view)). So too does Wittgenstein's *Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus* proceed in a fairly regimented fashion, albeit with a quixotic outcome that presages Wittgenstein's eventual amorphism of thought.

Finally (here), consider Kripke's writings on modal logic, or John Duns Scotus' argument for the existence of God. That latter is [notoriously intricate](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/duns-scotus/#ProExiGod), and though not as epic as, say, Wiles' proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, it still represents an example of where philosophically informed reasoning can be rigorously deductive (of course, the premises are not so stable, it turns out, but neither are [those](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.07445) of [set theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4223)).

Comment: Well, you've offered a challenge. I suppose the only way to settle it is to draw a complete argument map of one of those works. You say Scotus' work is "notoriously intricate" and it does have a clear single conclusion (that God exists); would you say that is the best candidate to be diagrammed?

Comment: @causative probably the easiest to extract from the original text (Scotus' nickname was "the Subtle Doctor"), but from Rawls' text would be the most rewarding and it has a strong index (IIRC he and his wife had a passion for indexes) that would help a lot in the attempt.

Answer (score 1):

**If one takes the formalist approach to be an abstraction of the use of conditionals in natural language and a chain is two or more links, then good philosophy often proceeds along chains of reasoning.** To see the form of such natural language argumentation takes, see [Toulmin's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Toulmin#The_Toulmin_model_of_argument) of using a warrant, rebuttal, and so forth to arrive at a conclusion for inference. The nice thing about an axiomatic approach is that is foundationalist, and if formal language is used instead of natural language, much simpler to see. That being said, however, a formalist presentation of inference can be viewed through the Tarskian lens of meta and object languages such that for every meaningful formalism as an object language, there must a natural language metalinguistic complement that makes the symbols meaningful. Through that reasoning, any formal language chain of inferences has a natural language counterpart. Whether or not a philosopher is systematic in their reasoning and the construction of their language determines whether or not seeing the inference is easy. Some philosophers like Descartes are very methodical precisely because they attempt to imitate Euclid; among modern philosophers, some philosophers like Searle are appreciably observant of keeping the presentation simple and building small chains that interconnect, and others, like Dennett, for instance, take a much more verbose and meandering approach to presenting their text. The Oxfordian Nicholas Shea in his [*Representations in Cognitive Science* (GB, the entire text is available through the site for free](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Representation_in_Cognitive_Science/CB5rDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1)) actually has an appendix where he presents his whole book with a summary that would allow you to diagram the inferences rather easily. That sort of courtesy, however, is extremely rarely given to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Philosophy isn't (generally) linear or teleological. It's more at hermeneutics: a system of interpretation and analysis that weaves back and forth within a conceptual domain to create a comprehensive and self-consistent understanding. Sometimes inferential chains are useful to get to specific points; inferential chains *are* linear and teleological, so appropriate to show specific relations. But the endpoint of an inferential chain in philosophy isn't an end in itself, but something that must be put in relation to other points to build a bigger picture.

Answer (score -1):

> Does philosophy involve long inferential chains?

The Cogito?

> I think; therefore, I am.

Seems very short to me.

What characterises at least Western philosophy is it analytical nature. You could say that Western philosophy is analytical hubris: All problems should be solvable through the rational analysis of common sense notions.

This is what Western philosophers have tried to achieve. They failed, most notably because there is still today no rational analysis of the Liar Paradox, 2,500 years after it was first minted.

Still, analysis seems to provide for long inferential chains, but this is nothing specific to philosophy. Mathematics and all sciences are bound to include long inferential chains as well.

Analysis is also present in mathematics. The difference is that mathematics does not purport to describe reality. Mathematicians can start from whatever system of axioms they please, irrespective of its potential denoting value.

Analysis is present in science as well and it is of course crucial to the scientific method that theories should be meant to refer to the real world by grounding its analyses on empirical data.

Philosophy is also meant to refer to the real world, although one might be sceptical of particular philosophies, this is nonetheless *always* the intention. Now the distinction between philosophy and science is that philosophy starts from common sense notions rather than empirical data, and is ordinarily conducted using some natural language, often extended with plenty neologisms, while science may start with natural language but will hopefully progress towards a mathematical expression.

So, philosophy may be characterised as analytical hubris conducted in some natural language with the intention of describing some real aspect of the real world by starting from common-sense notions.

Incidentally, rational analysis is also what distinguishes philosophy and science from religion. Most religions are not rational and not even analytical, but Catholic theology at least is analytical. The Catholic Church is the only institution to have ever tried to apply logic in a systematic and methodological way to its fundamental assumptions about the "real" world.

The difference, however, is that even the Catholic theology doesn't start from empirical evidence, like science does, or from common sense notions, like philosophy does.

Bear in mind that the Cogito is probably the most recognised of all philosophical wisdoms ever.